# API Usuário e senha na Header

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api

Fiz uma API e gostaria de saber se é relativamente seguro colocar um username e senha da forma que eu fiz

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

olha, o ideal é você fazer algo no estilo do `OAuth`.

Deixe uma `Url` para autenticação, esta URl deve esperar um `Body` com `Usuario` e `Senha`, o retorno desta seção deve ser um `Token`. Este Token deve ser unico para cada autenticação bem sucedida, o mesmo deve ser vinculado ao Usuario.

Por questões de segurança, aconselho que o Token seja armazenado como um array de 64 bytes no banco de dados, e o mesmo deve ser gerado através de um algoritmo forte, segue um exemplo em `C#` (apesar de você não ter especificado uma linguagem para o `BackEnd`).

```
var token = new byte[64];
var random = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
random.GetBytes(token);
```

Desta forma, mesmo que tenha dois usuarios logados utilizando o mesmo `Usuario`, você conseguira distinguir os dois através do `Token`.

E claro, o que irá trafegar no header é a representação Base64 deste Token.

Por fim, mais uma dica de segurança, utilize a mesma estrategia de geração do `Token` para a geração do `Salt` na hora de cadastrar à senha, mas uma vez, segue um exemplo em `C#`.

```
var password = "Minha@Senha$1234"
var salt = new byte[16];
var random = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
random.GetBytes(salt);

var pepper = salt.Sum(x => x);
var encrypted = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(password, salt, KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA512, 8000 + pepper, 64);
```

Answer (score 0):

É seguro porém não é a prática. Em todas as API's que eu conheço (CIELO, Google e Unlisted Images) sem exceção a autenticação é através de uma `key` que é gerada a partir de um [Guid](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%9Anico_Global), na qual pode ser tanto enviada pelo Header quanto no na URL de requisição, porém em todas a recomendação é através do Header.

Segue o exemplo da CIELO que pede merchantID e merchantKey **dentro do Header somente**.

[image: CIELO HEADER]

Comment: Eu não sei se eu consegui identificar a diferença entre o meu exemplo e o seu, me parece a mesma coisa

Comment: Não tem diferença, só quis dar um exemplo da CIELO, respondendo sua pergunta é seguro porém utilizar usuario/senha não é o que se usa no mercado. Vou atualizar a resposta com alguma informação a mais aliás.